# Need help writing birthday messages in Ruby

Tags: ruby

So my boyfriend's 20th birthday is coming up soon and he's a programmer, so I thought I would make him a cake with ruby code that says "happy 20th birthday, Kyle" . I would also like to give him a card that says "happy birthday to a special nerd", again, in ruby code.

Thanks for taking the time to read this. It means a lot to me.

Comment: The simplest way to do this in Ruby doesn't look very code-like: `p "happy birthday to a special nerd"` Dunno if that's got the right aesthetic.

Answer (score 5):

For a cake I would go with kopischke's answer, but for a card where there is more place I would choose to do this:

```
class Card
  attr_accessor :event, :person

  def initialize(event, person)    
    @event = event
    @person = person
  end

  def message
    "Happy #{event} to a #{person}!"
  end
end

card = Card.new('birthday', 'special nerd')
puts card.message
```

Here's how that looks like in an editor for a nicer syntax highlighting:

[image: card for Kyle in Sublime Text]

Answer (score 5):

I like mechanlicalfish's answer for a card but for a cake I would suggest:

```
@my_special_nerd = "Kyle"
puts "Happy Birthday #{@my_special_nerd}"
```

Just so you know, `@my_special_nerd = "Kyle"` assigns a variable called special nerd with the String Kyle. Kinda of like `x =` that you learned in Algebra but you can put sentences on the right side.

`puts` tells the program to print the program to standard output which is usually the programmer's screen.

`"Happy Birthday ..."` is a string. Strings are how we store sentences that programmers can read.

`"Happy Birthday #{@my_special_nerd}"` so `#{@my_special_nerd}` tells Ruby to replace the variable `@my_special_nerd` with the value Kyle.

If there program was run using Ruby, it would print to the programmer's screen:

`Happy Birthday Kyle`

Comment: Actually since you're using an instance variable, you could use "#@my_special_nerd", since that's a shorthand syntax option with Ruby. No curly braces required!

Answer (score 4):

The Ruby command to output some text is `puts`, i.e.  `puts "happy 20th birthday, Kyle"`. If you want a slightly more nerdy and less bland variant, use the `ap` command, which stands for *awesome print*:

```
ruby -r awesome_print -e 'ap "happy 20th birthday, Kyle"'
```

Write the part in double quotes in a different color (also note the nested single and double quotes), as that is what `ap` is for: structured, colorized output. Have fun :).

Answer (score 3):

I would write something like this on the cake, more UNIX-y and more geeky if you ask me. Also **modules** are more ruby-specific than classes, so:

```
$ cat > kyle.rb
module Bday
  def self.kyle
    "Happy 20th birthday, Kyle"
  end
end
puts Bday.kyle

^C
$ ruby kyle.rb
```

Then for the card I don't know really know. Maybe something encoded in base64 or XOR (depending what level of Geek we're talking about) might be more intriguing. Or simple md5sum-ed message in order for him to have to perform a sort of brute-force to find out.

Just a thought :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print "Happy Birthday!"
```

Comment: Hey, this looks like your first answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for contributing. Just so you know, if you surround code blocks with backticks(`), it'll give it some syntax high lighting. You can also add 4 blank spaces to indicate a code block as well.

Comment: @hichris123 there is no place for a syntax error on a birthday cake ;)

Comment: @mechanicalfish Not sure I follow you. Also, I have never coded in ruby and am not saying that I know anything about this; I was just formatting it as it came up in the Low Quality Posts queue.

Comment: @hichris123 oh, sorry I thought you added the // for a comment

Comment: @mechanicalfish Didn't realize that isn't the way to do it in ruby. Otherwise I would have taken it out. :P

Answer (score 1):

For the cake:

```
p "ibqqz!#{0x1f}ui!cjsuiebz-!Lzmf".chars.map {|c| (c.ord-1).chr}.join
```

and for the card:

```
p "ibqqz!cjsuiebz!up!b!tqfdjbm!ofse".chars.map {|c| (c.ord-1).chr}.join
```

These will respectively display

```
"happy 20th birthday, Kyle"
```

and

```
"happy birthday to a special nerd"
```

If you want "happy" capitalized. replace 'i' at the beginning with 'I'

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
class Song
  attr_accessor :lyrics
  def initialize
    @lyrics = []
  end
  def play
    @lyrics.each {|line| puts line}
  end
end

name = "Bubba"
age = 0x14  
song = Song.new
song.lyrics << "Happy #{age}th birthday to you"
song.lyrics << song.lyrics.first
song.lyrics << "Happy birthday, dear #{name}, happy birthday to you"
song.lyrics << song.lyrics.first
song.play
```

Unfortunately, this only works for Bubba's.  `song.play` would cause the following to be displayed:

```
Happy 20th birthday to you
Happy 20th birthday to you
Happy birthday, dear Bubba, happy birthday to you
Happy 20th birthday to you
```

`0x14` is the hexadecimal representation of the number decimal 20.